# meteor: no page updates after updating collection

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I have published and subscribed successfully two collections. On client side, i put the subscribe method into an autorun function and my collections updates every time i change some session variables. My data model looks like the following:

```
Topics: {
    _id: ObjectID,
    comments: [
        commentId1,
        commentId2,
        etc...
    ]
}

Comments: {
    _id: ObjectID,
}
```

When i create a new comment, i insert the comment in the `Comments` collection and update the `Topics` collection with a `$push` on the array. After this i expected, that meteor re-renders my page, but this happens only if i change my topic session variable and change it back or reload the page manually... Only then meteor renews the subscription.
Why is this so? I think i missed something... But the docs gave me no clues.

Comment: Do you have a lot of data on your database? You should probably try `meteor reset` once. But this will erase data.

Comment: I cannot test this, yet. But where do you see the problems?

Comment: @Prashant Ok, i have reseted my database and switched back to meteor master branch but nothing happens. The page refresh only on changing session variables.

Comment: Can you put up relevant code on gist?

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, please check if you're getting any warnings/errors on console and terminal running Meteor.

Comment: @Prashant I've created a [simple gist example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5113947) with console in- and outputs instead of an UI.

Comment: I misunderstood the docs: i thought, that every time after a change in the collection, the subscription renews. The code in my example works. Only the templates in my complexer main app, with nearly the same code - except session variables, doesn't work, yet. So the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: @Prashant The example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5149266) is one, which is not working, until you change a session value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the reason is that you are performing database insertion on client side, but can't tell why it's not rendering page again.

One more way you can do that is, perform insertion on server side using `Meteor.call()` as:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  ....
  ....
  Meteor.call('addComment', 'your_new_comment'); 
  ....
}
```

And on the server-side:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

  Meteor.Methods({
   'addComment' : function(data){
     //your insertion code here.
     Comments.insert(data);
   }
  });
}
```

The same you can do for `Topics` also. This will update the relevant data on server-side, and because you have already `published-subscribed` those data, it will be automatically published on client, even though the session variable doesn't changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do all my inserts and updates on the server (per `Meteor.call`) and my selects in `Meteor.publish`. And i think, this is the reason, anyway. Because in my first meteor app, i did all db performs on the client side and published all documents to the client - and i had not so much trouble with db changes. But i think, my later approach (and also your answer), is more *the meteor way*.